# Why is Springs auto generated pom file un parsable?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've been trying to setup a spring websocket server using the stat.spring.io  generator which generates a pom file etc.

It seems that the generated pomfile is unparsable for some reason and i've spent hours trying to fix it.

I've tried using Java 1.7 with spring 2.*.* to no avail.

Please can someone help explain why it might not be parsing:

Here is my full pomfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>ws-analytics-gateway</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ws-analytics-gateway</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Is that really the complete content? At least the closing `</project>` tag is missing. Also, what's the exact error message that you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pom.xml you have posted is not valid XML. it is missing a closing tag for project as mentioned above. Also, you mention using java 1.7 with spring 2.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#java-8-baseline-and-java-9-support states:

> Spring Boot 2.0 requires Java 8 as a minimum version.

I checked your XMl by pasting it here: https://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0 you may wish to have that check pass first.